# is that correct with immer or is that wrong?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to ask you is that immer or not ?

```
    addProduct: (state, action: PayloadAction<Omit<IProductsListDataOnPress, 'onPress' | 'onLongPress'>>) => {
      state.shopcart = [...state.shopcart, action.payload]
    },
    removeProduct: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ id: string; }>) => {
      state.shopcart = state.shopcart.filter(el => el.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
```

did I forgot something when to using immer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work totally fine.

The first one could also be

```js
    addProduct: (state, action: PayloadAction<Omit<IProductsListDataOnPress, 'onPress' | 'onLongPress'>>) => {
      state.shopcart.push(action.payload)
    },
```

Comment: thanks I doubt so many times so I ask little questions like this

Comment: If you haven't already, also give https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers a read :)